# How to simplify the code and is it necessary?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I work on the API in the Django REST Framework. And now there is such a problem: there is a ModelViewSet and in its functions the same request to the database, the same check in the `if` block. Is it possible to somehow move this matter into a separate function and how to do it?

```
class LinkViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = LinkSerializer
    queryset = Link.objects.all()


    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = Link.objects.filter(Q(user_id=self.request.user.id) & Q(id=kwargs["pk"])).first()

        if not instance:
            return Response(data="Not found", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        return super().retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = Link.objects.filter(Q(user_id=self.request.user.id) & Q(id=kwargs["pk"])).first()

        if not instance:
            return Response(data="Not found", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        return super().partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the code correctly, the intention is to limit queryset to allow access only to links owned by currently logged in user. For that, you can just override [get_queryset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself) method and that is it. DRF will take care of getting object from the queryset by id and throwing 404 if the object is not found.

```
class LinkViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = LinkSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Link.objects.filter(user_id=self.request.user.id)
```

Comment: oh,thank you very much). This solution really cleared my code of unnecessary methods

Answer (score 0):

You could do some of the implementation in a private method

```
def _link_objects_filter(self, pk):
    return Link.objects.filter(Q(user_id=self.request.user.id)
        & Q(pk)).first()
```

Or, taking it a step further, have a common implementation that uses `getattr` to decide which base implementation to use.

```
class LinkViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = LinkSerializer
    queryset = Link.objects.all()

    def _retrieve_op(self, method, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self._link_objects_filter(kwargs["pk"])
        if not instance:
            return Response(data="Not found", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return getattr(super(), method)(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._retrieve_op("retrieve", request, *args, **kw)

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._retrieve_op("partial_update", request, *args, **kw)
        
    def _link_objects_filter(self, pk):
        return Link.objects.filter(Q(user_id=self.request.user.id)
            & Q(pk)).first()
```

That could be further reduced with partial methods

```
import functools

class LinkViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = LinkSerializer
    queryset = Link.objects.all()

    def _retrieve_op(self, request, method, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self._link_objects_filter(kwargs["pk"])
        if not instance:
            return Response(data="Not found", status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return getattr(super(), method)(request, *args, **kwargs)

    retrieve = functools.partialmethod(_retrieve_op, "retrieve")
    partial_update = functools.partialmethod(_retrieve_op, "partial_update")
        
    def _link_objects_filter(self, pk):
        return Link.objects.filter(Q(user_id=self.request.user.id) & Q(pk)).first()
```

I'm not sure whether django meta programming will mess this up.